# Math equations on AI stackexchange

Tags: feature-request

I recently replied to a post on ai stackexchange, and I noticed that it is not possible to insert equations, unlike other websites like crypto stackexchange for example. I believe the library used on the latter to create mathematical equations is MathJax. Why is not there a similar tool on ai stackexchange? Wouldn't this be a very useful tool to use in posts?

Comment: TL;DR: I've poked the staff a couple times, they said they're considering it, and I think a site mod should send them an email.